# Polynomials are continuous with respect to the Zariski topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$. Show that if both $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ have the Zariski topology then all polynomials on $\mathbb{F}^n$
are continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p : \mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}$ be a polynomial. It suffices to show that the preimage of every closed set in $\mathbb{F}$ is closed in $\mathbb{F}^n.$ The closed sets of $\mathbb{F}$ are simply the finite sets and $\mathbb{F}$ itself. The preimage of $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{F}^n$ which is closed so if we can show the preimage of a point $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}$ is closed then we are done. That preimage consists of the points in $\mathbb{F}^n$ such that $p(x_1,\cdots, x_n) -\alpha =0,$ which is by definition closed.

Comment: I suppose you want to call the original polynomial $F$, and that you mean that the set of points such that $F(x_1,...,x_n)-p=0$ is the zero-locus of a polynomial, and hence closed ? (because it is certainly not finite)

Comment: @SamuelT Yes that's for pointing that out.

Comment: I see. I'm really stupid, that is very easy